# Get value of All element find by id starts with in PHP

Tags: php

I have HTML Like

```
<input type="text"  class="class1" id="Name_0" value="test"/>
<input type="text"  class="class1" id="Name_1" value="test1"/>
<input type="text"  class="class1" id="Name_2" value="test2"/>
<input type="text" id="mand_2" value="test2"/>
```

and I wants all that span value which id starts with "Name_" in PHP 
I tried as

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($key, 'Name_') === 0) {
            echo $value;            
        }
}
```

I am new for PHP 
Please anyone can help me
thanks in advance

Comment: You know `span` elements will not be included in the `POST` parameters in the first place, right?

Comment: I will replace the span element with input type text then how could i POST the value as i edited the question.

Comment: This new edit makes no sense anymore.

Comment: It seems you are newbie to php also web programming please read this book http://books.google.co.in/books?id=2S_Y6Zm02BQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=php&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q7hUVJzPNJKhugSE_oGAAg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBDgU#v=onepage&q=php&f=false

Comment: If you want to do this with POST, your `name=` artribution must include lblName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax to get every elemt which has an id assigned which starts with lblName_:

```
$html = '<span class="class1" id="lblName_0">test</span><span class="class1" id="lblName_1">test1</span><span class="class1" id="lblName_2">test2</span><span id="mand_2">test2</span>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($selector->query('//*[starts-with(@id, "lblName_")]') as $node) {
    var_dump($node->nodeValue) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You can see the result at http://ideone.com/ZVQkff

Answer (score 0):

You can not send span- Elements. If it needs to be a span-Element, you could read the innerHTML with JavaScript and send it with AJAX to your PHP-Server.

Comment: Mybe he's not aware of JS. By only using PHP he could add hidden-input fields. But without knowing what his programm should do, I could only assume what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

That what you want to achieve isn't doable with php. You can only get the content/value of forms including textareas, input fields, radio buttons and checkboxes. Javascript should be working fine in your case as you can get the content with `document.getElementById.innerHTML`.